# JS - Solidity: Events vs View Functions to retrieve data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, ethereum, solidity

I have a JavaScript/React FrontEnd where I want to retrieve and show variables that have been stored in my Solidity Smart Contract.
I know that I can emit an event each time I need to retrieve those variables and read from my JS app, however emit and store events will cost gas.
Why cannot simply continuous polling a GetData view function (using setInterval), where for example I recall data from my js app every 2 seconds?
As view functions cost no gas, why it is preferred to use events to store and retrieve data?

Answer (score 0):

Events are like notifications about the state changes in smart contract and are usually used in corresponding state changing functions. Events also cost less gas than a function call. Take a look at [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41984/gas-consumed-by-function-invoking-event/41988) question. Furthermore, Events are cheaper as compared to storing data in the contract. You can read more about it [here](https://media.consensys.net/technical-introduction-to-events-and-logs-in-ethereum-a074d65dd61e).

Also, `view` functions do cost gas if they are called from a transaction that results in state change of the contract